# Internet works but some programs won't connect to the internet (Steam, MSN, LoL)

Tags: windows-vista, networking

I went through the Program features to delete a bunch of random programs I dont use any more or never wanted in the first place. Then Windows Live Messenger and AVG updated and I threw a few things to the vault via AVG.

Firefox wouldn't connect after this happened and then later Windows Live wouldn't connect and I soon found out the Steam browser wouldn't either and I couldn't connect to the League of Legends server either.   I can still connect to Ventrillo and play online Steam games such as Counterstrike and Modern Warfare.

After calling Shaw for tech support they helped me get my Firefox working via using no proxy server but then told me they couldn't help me with the other programs ("we only supply internet and that's what we've done").

I had a similar problem a few months ago and was able to get someone else to fix it, said person is no longer available.  I believe he messed around with the internet protocol properties and the DNS server address to fix the issue.

Can anyone help me get back to business?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue talked to a friend of mine that had the issue.

Because i dont use internet explorer i didnt change the proxy on it, apparently all of those programs that didnt work use internet explorer to connect to their things.  I changed it to use no proxy and those programs work.

I have been advised that a virus caused me to connect through a proxy and when i removed the virus i couldnt connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like your DNS is the problem.

First thing I'd try is the Repair option on your network connection.

Secondly I'd look if there's anything in the hosts file:
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

If that doesn't work, see if you can download ComboFix* and / or SuperAntiSpyware and / or Malwarebytes AntiMalware and run full scans.

***** *ComboFix does not run on 64-bit Windows.*